# retrieving appointments

Tags: c#, devexpress

I am using devexpress xtrascheduler. I have created the custom appointment form.

Now I can add details in that form and it is showing on the scheduler cells also..but again when i click on the appointment(scheduler cell which is having a appointment)a new appointment form is opening..

But I want to open the from which is having the details which i already entered.

In simple terms, I will tell what i did and what i want

1.I have created a customeappointment form(instead of new appointment form)
2.I can assign appointments on the scheduler cell(it is showing on cell)
3.But when i close the form and then again when it is opened the appointment is not showing in the cell

help me please..

Answer (score 0):

Please review the Scheduler's demo project source code.  It shows how to create a custom appointment edit form and use it in conjunction with the scheduler.  Also, the [How to: Create a Custom EditAppointment Form with Custom Fields](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2288) topic shows how this can be done.  If these resources are not helpful to you, please post a sample project to our [support center](http://devexpress.com/support/center) and we will try to help you.